# Kotlin random integer

Tags: android, kotlin, random

Im trying to display random image whenever the app goes on. First I made a list with image ids and tried to make a random integer so that I can get random image each time by using the integer as an index of the list. Below is the code I tried.

```
val background_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.background_image)

val drawableList = mutableListOf<Int>(R.drawable.picture_0001,R.drawable.picture_0002,R.drawable.picture_0003)
val index = Random.nextInt(drawableList.size)
val test = (1..5).random()

Toast.makeText(this,test.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

background_image.setImageResource(drawableList[index])
```

`test` and the `Toast` part is just for checking if other random method works.
but both two ways doesn't work and shows the same random integer every time. Why isn't it working?
(minSDK 21).

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Im trying to make it to display different image randomly in each run but It just shows one image in every run time. (1..5).random() part also toasts the same integer each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different seed to get different results.

from [Random](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random.html)

> Two generators with the same seed produce the same sequence of values within the same version of Kotlin runtime.

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a seed.

```
val random = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
val list = listOf(1,2,3)
val randomInt = list[random.nextInt(list.size)]
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! By the way, what does "Two generators" mean? Is it "two" because I used "Random" twice in one project by "Random.nextInt(drawableList.size)" and "(1..5).random()"??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating a random number on your own, you can simply use the extension function of `Collection` class.

```
val list = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
val aRandomNumberFromList = list.random()
```

Comment: It still shows same images.. I think somthing got wrong with my project. In different project it works and the method which I tried also works.